# Copy Select-list values and create buttons with the same values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Its possible i do it?
I have a select-list and i want to create a list div with buttons with the same values, and when click in a button the select list change.

I need hide this select-list and just show buttons.

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irfbT.jpg)

My website : http://www.becannis.com.br/pd-45c046-bandana-flamingo.html?ct=1a7c1a&p=1&s=1

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18931775/6316091

Comment: Yes, i do it, but my ecommerce system dont understant the "new btn" and the "variations" value is not showed in cart-content. I need to do it, but copy and dont transform the select-list