# Add color option to converted attribute and terms buttons for variable WooCommerce product

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product

Having converted the drop-down for attribute and terms into buttons, I am looking for some help on adding color as an option for the color term.

**Current design:**
[image]

**End result:**
[image]

---

If the term name is Yellow, the background of that button becomes `#ffff00` and the color of it white (#fff). If the name is Blue, the background becomes `#0000ff` and the text white -- and so forth.

I just need help adding one and I'll do the rest myself.

---

Based on [How to convert select options (product attributes) to clickable divs in variable product page in WooCommerce?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67202847/11987538) answer code, this is my attempt:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'convert_attribute_and_terms_into_buttons' );
function convert_attribute_and_terms_into_buttons() { ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($){

    var clone = $( ".single-product div.product table.variations select" ).clone( true,true );

    $( ".single-product div.product table.variations select option" ).each( function() {

        $( this ).attr( 'data-parent-id', $( this ).parent().attr( 'id' ) );

        }
    );

    $( ".single-product div.product table.variations select option" ).unwrap().each( function() {

        if ( $ ( this ).val() == '' ) {

            $( this ).remove();

            return true;

        }

        var option = $( '<div class="custom_option" data-parent-id="'+$( this ).data( 'parent-id' )+'" data-value="'+$( this ).val()+'">'+$( this ).text()+'</div>' );

        $( this ).replaceWith( option );

        }
    );

    $( clone ).insertBefore( '.single-product div.product table.variations .reset_variations' ).hide();


    $( document ).on( 'click', '.custom_option', function() {

        var parentID = $( this ).data( 'parent-id' );

        $( '.custom_option[data-parent-id='+parentID+']' ).removeClass( 'on' );

        $( this ).addClass( 'on' );

        $( ".single-product div.product table.variations select#"+parentID ).val( $ ( this ).data( "value" ) ).trigger( "change" );

        }
    );

    $( ".single-product div.product table.variations select" ).each( function() {

        if ( $ ( this ).find( "option:selected" ).val() ) {

            var id = $( this ).attr( 'id' );

            $( '.custom_option[data-parent-id='+id+']' ).removeClass( 'on' );

            var value = $ ( this ).find( "option:selected" ).val();

            $( '.custom_option[data-parent-id='+id+'][data-value='+value+']' ).addClass( 'on' );

        }

    });
});

</script>

<style>
div.custom_option {

    display: inline-block;

    border: 1px solid #333;

    margin-right: 5px;

    padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;

    cursor: pointer;
}
div.custom_option.on {

    background-color: gray;

    color: white;
}
</style>
    <?php
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$( this ).val()` contains the value of the attribute. Because not every value is necessarily a color, we will search for it in an array, if the color name is found, we apply the background and text color code via CSS, to the element.

- [Used in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42750726/11987538) (search function)

So you get:

```php
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'convert_attribute_and_terms_into_buttons' );
function convert_attribute_and_terms_into_buttons() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        // Set colors with color code
        // background-color | text-color | color name
        var colors = { '#258DE8:#2B2F32': 'blue', '#ff0000:#ffffff': 'red', '#00F272:#ffffff': 'green' };
        
        var find = function( input, target) {
            var found;
            
            for ( var prop in input ) {
                if ( input[prop] == target ) {
                    found = prop;
                }
            };

            return found;
        };
        
        var selector = '.single-product div.product table.variations';
        
        var clone = $( selector + ' select' ).clone( true,true );

        $( selector + ' select option' ).each( function() {

            $( this ).attr( 'data-parent-id', $( this ).parent().attr( 'id' ) );

        });

        $( selector + ' select option' ).unwrap().each( function() {

            if ( $ ( this ).val() == '' ) {

                $( this ).remove();

                return true;

            }
            // Value
            var data_value = $( this ).val();
            
            // Search for value
            var found = find( colors, data_value.toLowerCase() );

            // When found
            if ( found ) {
                // Split a string into an array of substrings:
                var res = found.split( ':' );
                
                // First part
                var background_color = res[0];
                
                // Second part
                var text_color = res[1];
                
                // Apply
                var option = $( '<div style="color:' + text_color + ';background-color:' + background_color + ';" class="custom_option" data-parent-id="' + $( this ).data( 'parent-id' )+'" data-value="' + data_value + '">'+$( this ).text() + '</div>' );    
            } else {
                var option = $( '<div class="custom_option" data-parent-id="' + $( this ).data( 'parent-id' )+'" data-value="' + data_value + '">'+$( this ).text() + '</div>' );               
            }

            $( this ).replaceWith( option );

        });

        $( clone ).insertBefore( selector + ' .reset_variations' ).hide();


        $( document ).on( 'click', '.custom_option', function() {

            var parentID = $( this ).data( 'parent-id' );

            $( '.custom_option[data-parent-id='+parentID+']' ).removeClass( 'on' );

            $( this ).addClass( 'on' );

            $( selector + ' select#' + parentID ).val( $ ( this ).data( 'value' ) ).trigger( 'change' );

            }
        );

        $( selector + ' select' ).each( function() {

            if ( $ ( this ).find( 'option:selected' ).val() ) {

                var id = $( this ).attr( 'id' );

                $( '.custom_option[data-parent-id=' + id + ']' ).removeClass( 'on' );

                var value = $ ( this ).find( "option:selected" ).val();

                $( '.custom_option[data-parent-id=' + id + '][data-value=' + value + ']' ).addClass( 'on' );

            }

        });
    });
    </script>

    <style>
    div.custom_option {

        display: inline-block;

        border: 1px solid #333;

        margin-right: 5px;

        padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;

        cursor: pointer;
    }
    div.custom_option.on {

        background-color: gray;

        color: white;
    }
    </style>
    <?php
}
```